# Seaborn PairGrid map limitation for lower triangle

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, seaborn

I have a problem plotting a good density graph with appropriate limitation for lower triangle of my figures.
here's the code:

```
    g = sns.PairGrid(df, palette="Set2")
    g.map_upper(plt.scatter, s=10)
    g.map_upper(corrfunc)
    g.map_diag(sns.distplot, kde=False)
    g.map_lower(sns.kdeplot, cmap="Blues_d")
    g.map_lower(corrfunc)
    g.set(xlim=(-1, None), ylim=(-5, None))
```

The result:

[image: correlation]

Unfortunately, I can not set the lower triangle of the density plot.
`set` can only change the limitation on the overall plot.
Can you suggest any alternative that can only effect the lower triangle?